# Could JSP file not found be a bug in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

I have followed the official files and package structure of spring boot in my application. But I am still getting a whitelabel page error. Most of the answers and suggestions dont solve this problem.

Could this be a bug in spring boot?

[image: Whitelabel Error Page]

Below is how I have put my codes and the structure of how files and folders are arranged.

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
 public class Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

 }
```

**Controller**

```
 @Controller
 public class UserController  { 
       @RequestMapping("/")
       public String index(HttpServletRequest request){
       request.setAttribute("mode", "MODE_HOME");
       return  "homepage";
 }}
```

**homepage.jsp**

```
 <body>
 <c:choose>
 <c:when test="${mode=='MODE_HOME'}">
 <h1>Mambo, This is home page </h1>
 </c:when> </c:choose>
 </body>
```

****application.properties****

```
 spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/view/
 spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

****pom.xml****

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.1</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.samaritan</groupId>
  <artifactId>samaritanweb</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>samaritanweb</name>
  <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

  <properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
  </properties>
  
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
  <optional>true</optional>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
  <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
  <optional>true</optional>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>  
  <scope>provided</scope>     
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
  <groupId>jstl</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>

   </project>
```

[image: Structure Layout]

**NB:** Using Visual Studio Code Version 1.52.1

Comment: Anything is possible, but it would be wise to assume that it is not a Spring bug unless you have clear evidence that it is.

Comment: Sir @StephenC you are wright, It just that I have try solve that it with almost every answers and suggestion in different posts with no success. Kind of  stuck

Comment: @StephenC Imaging that you might have a project working fine but after reboot the system and lunch the app again you get that WhiteLabel Error Page

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your main class like this

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: I have try to change main class as you suggested but still the same error

Comment: I have reproduced your example and it works. But also you have an error in you pom.xml: replace last </dependency>  tag with </dependencies>

Comment: Likewise on my side it used to work fine, but after I reboot my PC and lunch the application the error popup. Sorry </dependencies> was a typing error.Changed.

Comment: This is very strange. Do you check the process that handle requests (with jps or ps aux)? Maybe there is another instance of tomcat with old version of app starting with your pc?
Try to add server.port=9999 (for example) in application.properties and check the localhost:9999.

Also you can clean your maven local repository

Comment: How do I clean up the maven local repository with VSCode?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify what requests to be received by the controller (GET, POST, etc..).

```
@Controller
 public class UserController  { 
       @RequestMapping("/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public String index(HttpServletRequest request){
       request.setAttribute("mode", "MODE_HOME");
       return  "homepage";
 }}
```

or

```
 @Controller
 public class UserController  { 
       @GetMapping("/")
       public String index(HttpServletRequest request){
       request.setAttribute("mode", "MODE_HOME");
       return  "homepage";
 }}
```

Comment: tried both of the above options but the same error