# Spring web application.Unable to view the view page

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Getting the following error in my console

printing ra

Dec 19, 2020 2:19:52 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping for GET /FirstSpringWebExample/WEB-INF/hello.html

My files are as below,
web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>FirstSpringWebExample</display-name>
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
  </servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

HelloWeb-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package = "com.sri.controller" />

<bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/" />
  <property name = "suffix" value = ".html" />
 </bean>

 </beans>
```

HelloController.java

```
package com.sri.controller;

 import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
  import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

 @Controller
 public class HelloController {
  @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
      model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");
      System.out.println("printing");
      return "hello";
   }
  @RequestMapping(value = "/hellot", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String printHellos(ModelMap model) {
      model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");
      System.out.println("printing ra");
      return "hello";
   }
   }
```

hello.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Hello Spring MVC</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>${message}</h2>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Here in above code.Controller is working fine but view is not working.Here it is getting as requested resource not available.

[image]

Comment: This error is real frustrating. I dealing with the similar problem with JSP file [/WEB-INF/homepage.jsp] not found.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65366871/could-jsp-file-not-found-be-a-bug-in-spring/65369026#65369026

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the html extension to jsp extension.Now it is working (Dont know why InternalViewResolver cant render html page)